# CountVectorizer does not work on training data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm making classification with text using scikit learn. I have used `CountVectorizer`. I head that `CountVectorizer` should be used only on training data, not to all data (features).

I have used it on all data (features) and the code worked, but when I used it on training only, it shows this error:

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use
>   X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

This is my code (code is very simple its just for example):

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


df = pd.DataFrame({"second":["yes ofc", "not a chance", " hell no", "yes yes yes", "yes",'yes maybe', 'yes ofc', 'no not'],
                  "third":["true","false", "false", "true", "false", "true","false", "false"]})

##CHANGE HERE
results = df['third']
features = df['second']

cv = CountVectorizer()  
#features = cv.fit_transform(features) #it worked

features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

#features_train = cv.fit_transform(features_train).toarray() #it does not work
#result_train = cv.fit_transform(result_train).toarray() #it does not work

cls = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)

acc_prediction  = model.predict(features_test)
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(result_test, acc_prediction)

print(accuracy_test)
```

Comment: You might want to convert your strings to ints or bools. It won't fix your problem, but it'll be better down the line.

Comment: this is only an example.  Real values are string that are much longer and there are a lot of values

Comment: You'll still want to make them categorical.

Comment: I guess the results should be df['third'] because results are the labels (true, false) here.

Comment: `result_train` is not supposed to be fed to `CountVectorizer` ?

Comment: I read on documentation that ONLY train data should be fed to CountVectorizer

Answer (score 2):

You should only *train (or `fit`)* the counter vectorizer on the training data, but run on both training and test data.

After creating the `CountVectorizer`:

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
```

And spliting the data into training and test sets:

```
features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
```

`fit_transform` the `features_train` before continuing, because you want to train your actual classifier using the count vectorizer transformed data:

```
features_train = cv.fit_transform(features_train)
```

Now, after this, `cv` will be *fit* on just the training data, and have transformed the training data as well. Now, train the actual classifier using this transformed data:

```
cls = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)
```

Now, your classifier is trained using the *count vectorized* training data. While testing the accuracy on the test data, first transform the test data using the same count vectorizer:

```
features_test = cv.transform(features_test)
```

Notice that you aren't fitting it again, we're just using the already trained count vectorizer to transform the test data here. Now, use your trained decision tree classifier to do the prediction:

```
acc_prediction = model.predict(features_test)
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(result_test, acc_prediction)
print(accuracy_test)
```

Comment: So I should run `CountVectorizer` on `features_train` and `features_test `, not on `features_train` and `result_train`, right?
If I do like you told me, Ill prevent overfitting?

Comment: Running `CountVectorizer` on `features_train` and `features_test` instead of `result_train` doesn't have to do anything with overfitting. It's just that you don't run count vectorizer on the the labels (`result_train`), you just run it on the data on which you're training your model.

Comment: @AhmadKhan Since you're splitting your data into training and test sets, the dimensions are going to be the same for both. But how do you predict for test data that is separate from the training data? Because running the cv.transform would give an error due to dimension mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

For applying the fitted model on test data, use `.transform()`. The below code would be my suggestion!

Also `.toarray()` is a costly operation of converting the sparse matrix to dense. Hence don't use it until it is absolutely required. The DecisionTree can work with sparse matrix itself.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


df = pd.DataFrame({"second":["yes ofc", "not a chance", " hell no", "yes yes yes", "yes",'yes maybe', 'yes ofc', 'no not'],
                  "third":["true","false", "false", "true", "false", "true","false", "false"]})

##CHANGE HERE
results = df['third']
features = df['second']

cv = CountVectorizer()  

features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

features_train = cv.fit_transform(features_train) 
features_test = cv.transform(features_test) 

cls = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)

acc_prediction  = model.predict(features_test)
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(result_test, acc_prediction)

print(accuracy_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
features = cv.fit_transform(features)
X_train , X_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(features , test_size=0.3 , random_state=0)
Y_train , Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(results, test_size=0.3 , random_state=0)
```

Comment: But what am I getting with this?
I thinkg that I should convert X_train  and Y_train

Answer (score 0):

The below code works. I guess you did wrong with assigning results and features.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


df = pd.DataFrame({"second":["yes ofc", "not a chance", " hell no", "yes yes yes", "yes",'yes maybe', 'yes ofc', 'no not'],
                  "third":["true","false", "false", "true", "false", "true","false", "false"]})

##CHANGE HERE
results = df['third']
features = df['second']

cv = CountVectorizer()  
features = cv.fit_transform(features) #it worked

features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

#features_train = cv.fit_transform(features_train) #it does not work
#result_train = cv.fit_transform(result_train) #it does not work

cls = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)

acc_prediction  = model.predict(features_test)
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(result_test, acc_prediction)

print(accuracy_test)
```

If you want to run CountVectorizer individually on train set as well as on test set, then below is the way to do that:

```
{SAME AS ABOVE TILL HERE}

results = df['third']
features = df['second']

cv = CountVectorizer()  

features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

features_train = cv.fit_transform(features_train) #it does not work

cls = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)

acc_prediction  = model.predict(cv.transform(features_test))
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(result_test, acc_prediction)

print(accuracy_test)
```

Comment: yeah, I did that wrong. But this is not answer to my question.
Should i run CountVectorizer only on training data or all data?
How can I run CountVectorizer on training data only?

Comment: You need to run CountVectorizer on all data. You have to convert train data, as well as test data in the same way. You cannot just convert train data only and use test data as in the raw format.